# Thousand separator in awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I would like to print thousand separator with `awk's printf`.

In `bash`, it is pretty straightforward:

```
> printf "a %'d b \n" 1234567
a 1,234,567 b
> LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf8
> printf "a %'d b \n" 1234567
a 1 234 567 b
```

With an `awk` program it almost worked:

```
> cat > print.awk
{ printf "a %'d b\n",$1}
> echo 1234567 | awk -f print.awk
a 1,234,567 b
```

(Locale seems to be lost ... )

And in command line:

```
> echo 1234567 | awk '{printf "%d\n",$1;}'
1234567
> echo 1234567 | awk '{printf "%'d\n",$1;}'
> echo 1234567 | awk '{printf "%\'d\n",$1;}'
```

**Note**

I have a workaround, I just want to use `%'d` if possible.

Comment: Do you mean `echo 1234567 | awk '{printf "%'\''d\n",$1;}'`?

Comment: @Chaos that's what I meant. Any chance I might use my locale's ?

Comment: @Archemar: Just set the locale when calling `awk` or export it before calling `awk`.

Comment: If you want `awk` to notice your change to `LC_NUMERIC`, you need to export that variable. Use `export LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf8` instead of the simple assignment, or run `awk` in a modified environment: `LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf8 awk ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a variable to hold `'`:

```
echo 1234567 | q="'" awk '{printf "%"ENVIRON["q"]"d\n", $1}'
1,234,567
```

or use `\047` to represent `'`:

```
echo 1234567 | awk '{printf "%\047d\n", $1}'
```

This will work in any POSIX awk (not work with `mawk`).

With `gawk`:

```
echo 1234567 | awk '{printf "%""\x27""d\n", $1}'
```

Comment: locale setting seems to work when I use `LANG=` but not when i use `LC_NUMERIC=` .

Comment: @Archemar: What is your OS and default locale?

Comment: default are : PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS" , LANG=en_US.utf-8

Comment: Ubuntu seems to use `LANG` over `LC_NUMERIC`. `echo 1234567 | LC_NUMERIC=C LANG=en_US.utf8 awk -vq="'" '{printf "%"q"d\n", $1}'` return `1,234,567`. While `man 7 locale` said that `LANG` won't override any `LC_*` if `LC_*` set. Bug?

Comment: @Archemar: Well, sorry, I have mess up my test. `LC_ALL` was set to `en_US.utf8` in my test machine. You should check yours locale setup.

Comment: Wow! A good answer gets no upvote after 3 years (I must rectify that situation). I prefer the octal escape sequence but it’s recommended not to use hexadecimal escape sequences as they do not work reliably across all systems – see [Print a Single Quote](http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote)