# Removing "," for calculation and adding it back using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file as

```
January 124,567.89
Feburary        234,567.78
March   349,123.77
April   112,248.00
May     107,345.22
June    180,670.23
July    122,457.03
August  345,789.99
September       234,567.90
October 145,890.95
Novemeber       245,789.76
December        111,890.22
```

I have awk function written as:

```
{


removecommas()
}
function removecommas(total)

{
gsub(",","",$2)

total+=$2
return total
}


function addcommas()

{
total=removecommas(total)

return sub(/[1-9]{3}/,"&,") total

}

END{
print addcommas()
}
~
```

I want to add values `$2` but before that I want to do:-

- remove commas
- before printing add commas and print total results

I'm stuck:-

- How to pass results of one function to another?
- `sub function` how to make it run inside a another function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not directly an answer, but inspired by [Thousand separator in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228298/thousand-separator-in-awk)

```
function addcommas()
{
removecommas(total)
return sprintf ("%'.2f",total) ;
}
```

or a more straightforward approach

```
function  addcommas()
{
t2 = total ;
sub(/[1-9]{3}/,"&,",t2) ;
return t2 ;
}
```

I don't think awk will allow lambda expression style like `sub() arg`. `sub` apply to `$0` or third argument.

Comment: excellent +1 thats so neat, only problem left is to `removecommas()` to return results in total.

Comment: edited, however, you use both a global var and a return value.